# Podman containers quit all at once on a server

Tags: containers, podman

I have a bunch of Podman containers based on the `python:3.10-slim` docker image, running on a cloud server with the following things inside:

- `Xvfb` to provide a virtual screen
- A Java application that needs a screen for it to run
- A Python script that monitors and controls the Java application (restarting it if needed)

It has been working just fine for several months but then I had to update the Java application and this week, during the nights, the containers simply stop. All 16 of them about the same time.

Their status becomes `Created` - not `Exited`, even though they have been running before.

And in the logs, I see the following line at the end:

```
java: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

in one of them I found a longer one:

```
java: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
java: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Terminated
```

I can't figure out what causes this phenomena because even if the Java app dies, it would be just restarted by the Python script, it wouldn't bring down the whole container.

Now, the Java app is a resource hog and with 16 instances running the server was at around 80% memory usage, so it might be that there's a memory usage spike which takes it to, or near, 100%. I don't have a logging of memory usage yet, so I don't know whether this actually happened or not. Would that cause this phenomenon? How does Podman handles memory shortage?

Does anybody have a theory as to why the containers would go to the `Created` status all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, there was no response to this question whatsoever.

Anyways, I figured it out.

As I suspected it was the low memory that caused all containers to quit at the same time.

First, I shut down a couple of containers which could be restarted easily when needed. That prevented the shutdown en-masse. So, we got the server upgraded to a higher tier with more RAM and now the problem does not repeat. The containers stay running as they should.

I also implemented a memory usage monitoring and from that I could see that the used memory with all containers running, eventually reached and went past the previously available RAM.

I hope this information will be useful for someone in the future who runs into it.